# Displaying Virtual Functions using loops

Tags: c++, polymorphism

#### Problem

I'm having a try at understanding virtual functions in polymorphism. I want to output from a polymorphic function multiple times using a `while` loop.

Where do I place the loop?

The output I'm receiving is only 3 outputs, each from the `Ninja` and `Monster` class.

#### Code

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <algorithm> 

using namespace std; 

class Enemy 
{  

public: 
    virtual void attack()
    { 
    }
}; 


class Ninja: public Enemy  
{  
public: 
    void attack()
    {
        cout << "Ninja attack -" << endl;
    }

};


class Monster : public Enemy
{
public:
    void attack()
    {
        cout << "Monster eat -" << endl;
    }

};
int main()
{ 
    Ninja n; 
    Monster m; 
    Enemy *enemy1 = &n; 
    Enemy *enemy2 = &m; 
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 2)
    {
        enemy1->attack();
        enemy2->attack();

        i++;
    }


    system("pause"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the code that you have written produces the expected result.

What exactly are you expecting? What is it that bothers you?

Also, this is not much, but regarding the way you are doing things, you should use a `for` loop, unless there's a specific reason for the `while` loop.

Comment: @Grybouili ahhhh very silly me, the output I want was `"Ninja Attack '"` newline `"Monster eat -"` newline `"Ninja Attack '"` newline `"Monster eat -"`. I totally forgot that programs output from `0` not `1`, rookie error. Thank you for your advice though I appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome I guess ^^ even tho I don't really get what you mean by "programs output from 0 not 1"...

Comment: @Grybouili doesn't matter, its sorted now anyways